# UPDATE using case when exists ( don't get the right result)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update, business-intelligence

i'm trying to update a table that is alimented by 2 flows, the 1st one i have to make FillRateCode (the column i want to update) equal to FillRateCode from BWH_OTC_Order but for the 2nd flow i put it equal to '-1'

this is my script:

```
use BITS
;with tmp as ( 
select SalesOrderItemNum, SalesOrderNum, FillRateCode
From
BWH_OTC_Order
INNER JOIN REF_Company Comp
ON (Comp.CompanyCode= BWH_OTC_Order.CompanyCode AND Comp.DivisionCode='TEE')
where RevisedPGIDate is not null
)

UPDATE bits_tee.dbo.DMT_TEE_OTC_OrderFulFill
SET FillRateCode = case when  exists ( select 1 from tmp) then tmp.FillRateCode else '-1' end
FROM bits_tee.dbo.DMT_TEE_OTC_OrderFulFill DMT
left outer join tmp
on tmp.SalesOrderItemNum = DMT.SalesOrderItemNum
and tmp.SalesOrderNum = DMT.SalesOrderNum
```

and this is the result i get

```
NB           BWH_FillRateCode   DMT_FillRateCode
124457       NULL               NULL
73991        0                  0
457507       1                   1
28632       -1                  -1
4849         2                   2
34262       3                    3
```

for nulls the correct resault is to get '-1' in DMT_FillRateCode

any issues?

Thx by advence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` with something else. Your `exists( select 1 from tmp)` is pointless since it only checks if there are any rows (so not only related rows).

```
WITH tmp 
     AS (SELECT SalesOrderItemNum, 
                SalesOrderNum, 
                FillRateCode 
         FROM   BWH_OTC_Order 
                INNER JOIN REF_Company Comp 
                        ON ( Comp.CompanyCode = BWH_OTC_Order.CompanyCode 
                             AND Comp.DivisionCode = 'TEE' ) 
         WHERE  RevisedPGIDate IS NOT NULL) 
UPDATE DMT 
SET    DMT.FillRateCode = ISNULL(tmp.FillRateCode, '-1') 
FROM   bits_tee.dbo.DMT_TEE_OTC_OrderFulFill DMT 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp 
                    ON tmp.SalesOrderItemNum = DMT.SalesOrderItemNum 
                       AND tmp.SalesOrderNum = DMT.SalesOrderNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question, but if you just want to replace null values with -1 you can use the isnull function

```
isnull(tmp.FillRateCode,-1) -- I'm guessing the -1 is an int, and not a char '-1'
```

instead of

```
case when  exists ( select 1 from tmp) then tmp.FillRateCode else '-1' end
```